# Como agregar enlaces vinculo a href a los dropdown-toggle de un menú bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy queriendo agregarle vinculo a los a href de un menu como ejemplo Chapas y chapas acanaladas que vinculen a un sitio pero no me deja. 
Quería saber como si hay alguna forma que ademas de que abra su respectiva solapa vincule a una pagina.

adjunto un fragmento de código donde quiero el vinculo.

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://www.google.com/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
```

Por otro lado como hacer para que en mobile el menu no quede desplegado y se contraiga.

```css
.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 41px, 0px);
  top: -43px!important;
  left: 252px!important;
  will-change: transform;
  background: #868686;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .hijas-de-hijas {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 41px, 0px);
  top: -42px!important;
  left: 218px!important;
  will-change: transform;
  background: #868686;
  border-radius: initial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown-item.active,
.dropdown-item:active {
  background-color: #f5131f;
  color: #fff!important
}

.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}

.categoria-prod #collapsingNavbar .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod {
  background-color: #f5131f;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .btn-dropdown {
  background-color: #f5131f;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: initial!important;
  border: initial!important;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  border-color: initial!important;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .btn-dropdown i {
  float: right;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-collapse {
  padding-top: 0!important;
  background-color: #454545;
  border-radius: initial;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-collapse li {
  margin: 18px 15px 18px 5px;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-collapse li a {
  padding: 0px 0px 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-collapse li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dcdcdc;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-collapse li .padre li {
  margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-collapse li:last-child {
  margin: 18px 15px 8px 5px;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .navbar-collapse li .padre li:last-child {
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 5px;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 107%;
  background-color: #868686;
  margin-left: -1px;
  width: 100%
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  border-radius: initial
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu .submenu-hijo {
  left: 102%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dcdcdc
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu>li .submenu-hijo li {
  margin: 8px 10px 8px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: initial;
}

.categoria-prod .bg-prod .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu>li .submenu-hijo li a {
  font-size: 14px
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#collapsingNavbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  top: 57px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container categoria-prod pt-3 pt-lg-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 p-0 pl-lg-0 pr-lg-3">
      <div class="bg-prod">
        <div class="py-lg-3 ">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a id="dLabel" role="button" class="btn btn-dropdown" href="/page.html" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
                Producto 
                <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level navbar-collapse collapse " role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" id="collapsingNavbar">
              <li><a href="#">Hierro</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Perfiles</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="www.google.com">Chapas
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu padre">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="www.google.com">Chapas acanaladas
                     <span class="fa fa-chevron-right float-right mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu-hijo">
                      <li><a href="www.google.com">Chapa Acanalada Prepintada</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Tubos y caños</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Metal desplegado y rejilla</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Aislaciones y membranas</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Clavos y tornillos</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Alambres y tejidos</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Todo para herrería</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Soldadoras</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Herramientas eléctricas</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Tubos y caños</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Metal desplegado y rejilla</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Aislaciones y membranas</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Clavos y tornillos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Alambres y tejidos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Todo para herrería</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Soldadoras</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Herramientas eléctricas</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Pero si tu botón de dropdown va a mostrar otras opciones para que quieres que abra otro enlace? Ya no tendria sentido, o bien quieres lo uno o lo otro

Comment: Hola mira es medio rebuscado lo que me piden ya el HTML se va integrar luego en un wordpress woocomerce y me piden que cuando haga click en el menu desplegable en CHAPA muestre una pagina que seria como una especie de category con todas categoría de CHAPA como CHAPA ACANALADAS, etc. Y cuando hagas click en CHAPA ACANALADAS me muestre un archive con CHAPA PREPINTADA Etc y de ahi click al single, no se si se comprende. Si quizás es medio de gusto hacer todo ese proceso, pero me lo piden así.un ejemplo seria como esta pagina https://www.storehaus.com.ar/ en el menu producto.

Comment: Si es así, tienes que cambiar tu código, para que el menú desplegable se abra al pasar el mouse sobre el menú y para que se abra otro enlace al hacer click

Comment: Osea que no podría usar este ejemplo que estoy adjuntando arriba? tendría que buscar otro tipo de dropdown?

Comment: revisa esto: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Comment: Sip, porque así como está al hacer click se mostrarán las opciones pero a la vez ya te mandará a otra página y ya no podrás ver las subopciones

Comment: Claro, bueno tendré que ver algún otro ejemplo es medio raro, pero me lo pidieron así.

Comment: ahí encontré uno que me sirvió, pero tengo un problema, ahí edito el archivo.

Comment: Ahí edite el código, el problema es cuando quiero pasarme de una solapa a otra que desaparece cuando quiero moverme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

empezando por tu segunda pregunta puedes simplemente utilizar el siguiente script

```
if( isMobile.any() ) alert('Mobile');
```

preguntas si es un dispositivo movil, si lo es llamas a tu collapse:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
```

y respecto a su primera pregunta puedes utilizar un evento onclick, por ahora es la unica solucion que puedo darte, ya que el bootstrap desabilita los links dentro de su navbar. utiliza el evento onclick dentro de la etiqueta a:

```
<a onclick="abrelink('https://www.google.com.ec')" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >
```

y pasale el enlace que desees, luego mediante javascript, has lo siguiente:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function abrelink(url){
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.style="display:none";
        a.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
   </script>
```

lo que hace esta funcion es crear una nueva etiqueta  de html, ponerla oculta, insertarla en el documento con la url especifica, abrir el enlace y eliminar esta etiqueta para que no quede basura en tu documento.

Comment: Entonces poniendo este script if( isMobile.any() ) alert('Mobile'); $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');  haria que en version mobile no quede desplegado?

Comment: exactamente, quitale el alert(), solo seria if( isMobile.any() )  $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');

Comment: sabes que no me funciono.

Comment: bueno tienes otra opcion, esa es una funcion que detecta el navegador si es de escritorio o móvil... o has la pregunta asi
 if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
   console.log('Esto es un dispositivo móvil');
}
https://blog.endeos.com/como-detectar-un-dispositivo-movil-con-jquery/
la otra opción amigo es detectar el tamaño del navegador.... preguntas si window.innerHeight< 100px o ajustalo a tus necesidades...

Comment: imagino que has estado probando hacer la pantalla mas pequeña, conectate a la ip desde tu movil y prueba haber si te resulta... pero de lo que si estoy seguro y lo probe es del $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');... con eso ocultas el navbar...

Comment: if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide'); 
}
utilizalo asi, te servirá, ya lo probé en mi dispositivo movil...

Comment: a ver voy a probar y chequear en mi dispositivo

Comment: osea solo lo voy a ver desde mi telefono si yo quiero inspeccionarlo desde el navegador con la herramientda de visualización de dispositivos no?

Comment: si ahí lo probé y anduvo bien